# C# controller does omit a property of a XML child element

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, entity-framework, linq

My task is to debug a rather large (and undocumented) ASP.NET project, more specifically the controller of an endpoint which looks as follows (shortened and pseudonymized by me, but otherwise not modified):

```cs
namespace myAPI.Controllers
{
    public class MyViewController: BaseController
    {
        private myContext _db => ServiceLocator.Db;

        [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<MyViewDto>))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetView(int? selectedEntityId)
        {
            var overallViews = inputPages[0].MyViews.ToList();
            for (int j = 1; j < inputPages.Count; j++)
            {
                var MyViewsTemp = inputPages[j].MyViews.
                    Where(x => x.Entity == selectedEntityId).ToList();
                MyViews.AddRange(MyViewsTemp);
            }

            var result = myViews.GroupBy(x => x.Position).
                Select(x => new MyViewDto
                {
                    Adjustments = x.Sum(y => y.Adjustments),
                    children = x.Select(Mapper.Map<MyViewDto>),  // <-- What exactly does this do?
                    PositionId = x.Key?.Id,
                    PositionName = x.Key?.Name,
                    Value = x.Sum(y => y.Value),
                    ValueAdjusted = x.Sum(y => y.ValueAdjusted),
                });
            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
}
```

As expected, the endpoint delivers a nested XML of the following structure, but **sometimes the certain properties like `ValueAdjusted` is empty for the (1st level) children, which I do not understand.**

**Intended behavior:** If child `i` is a leaf-node (=no subsequent children), the `ValueAdjusted = x.Sum(y => y.ValueAdjusted)` should just give back the `inputPages[i].ValueAdjusted` of that node, or does it?

An engineered example:

```xml
<MyViewDto xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<MyViews>
  <MyViewDto>
    <Adjustments>45818816</Adjustments>
    <PositionId>10</PositionId>
    <PositionName>Big Brother Bank</PositionName>
    <Value>299792458.00</Value>
    <children>
      <RunoffViewDto>
        <Adjustments i:nil="true"/>
        <PositionId>10</PositionId>
        <PositionName>Big Brother Bank</PositionName>
        <SubPositionId>1</SubPositionId>
        <SubPositionName>Assets A</SubPositionName>
        <Value>19955366.62</Value>
        <ValueAdjusted i:nil="true"/>
        <children i:nil="true"/>
      </RunoffViewDto>
      <RunoffViewDto>
        <Adjustments i:nil="true"/>
        <PositionId>10</PositionId>
        <PositionName>Big Brother Bank</PositionName>
        <SubPositionId>2</SubPositionId>
        <SubPositionName>Assets B</SubPositionName>
        <Value>19955366.62</Value>
        <ValueAdjusted i:nil="true"/>
        <children i:nil="true"/>
      <RunoffViewDto>
    </MyViewDto>
</MyViews>
```

Any help and explanations is much appreciated!

Comment: You say JSON several times, but the engineered example is clearly XML. The mapper call will map all elements of `x` (the group) to instances of `MyViewDTO`. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Thanks for the hint! It is XML everywhere, I just corrected it. (Background: In between the other code, JSONs where passed along, but for my issue, that's actually not relevant).

Comment: `Mapper.Map<MyViewDto>` is a [static method of AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/v8.1.1/src/AutoMapper/Mapper.cs#L77) that maps the incoming object to the target type, here `MyViewDto`.  See: https://docs.automapper.org/en/v8.0.0/Static-and-Instance-API.html.  Of note, it seems that this static API was removed in the latest major release of AutoMapper, [release 9.0.0](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/releases/tag/v9.0.0).

Comment: @dbc Interesting indeed. So you are guessing the automapper is the culprit? How do I get more info if sich a mapping fails or defaults to `null`?

Comment: What I mean is that the static method `Mapper.Map<MyViewDto>` seems to have been removed from the latest version of AutoMapper, version 9.0.0.  If you were to upgrade to that version your code would not compile.

Comment: *So you are guessing the automapper is the culprit?* - I don't really know, your question doesn't have a complete [mcve]; what it does have is not enough for me to guess what the problem is.  All I was trying to do with my comment was to offer some information concerning your code comment `// <-- What exactly does this do?`.